# MapStruct not generating Mapper implementations/ empty generated folder - Plain Eclipse + Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, mapstruct, annotation-processing

Since I couldn't find any answer to my issue after a long research neither on Stackoverflow nor in the [MapStruct-Users Group](https://groups.google.com/g/mapstruct-users)/ [Github Discussions](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/discussions) I'm posting it here again.

We started to use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) in our project and configured the annotation processor according to the [user/ setup guides](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/). However the "generated" folder stays empty and doesn't contain the generated *MapperImpl classes.

Unlike many similar questions we're integrating the plain Jar directly into Eclipse without any support of a build tool like Maven or Gradle (hence the issue. We're using ANT to generate our final artifacts, but for the problem to integrate it into Eclipse it shouldn't matter).

The setup:

- Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0)
- Java 1.8.0_202 (that's with which I tried it actually also 1.8.0_341 could be used, but I don't have it at hand now)
- MapStruct: 1.5.3 - mapstruct-processor-1.5.3.Final.jar
- The [MapStruct Eclipse-Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mapstruct-eclipse-plugin) is ***not*** installed

I've followed the instructions from the [setup articles](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/) and enabled the annotation processing and specific Jar in the factory path, however the "generated" folder remains empty:

[image]

[image]

The difference to the instructions are the folder names "generated" instead of ".apt_generated" - I guess this shouldn't be the reason.

Another interesting fact:
Once opening the MapStruct-Mapper classes/ interfaces and triggering a change therein, Eclipse successfully recognizes this change and is able to process the annotations, so that the corresponding *MapperImpl classes are generated (only for the modified files, not for all!). Simply adding and immediately removing a whitespace (so that effectively there is not even a change) is enough to do so.

Unfortunately the Mappers generated with this approach are removed upon the next "clean" operation (`Project > Clean...`) and the process of manually triggering changes in the corresponding classes would need to be repeated - but this is not a workable solution.

Actually the expectation would be that especially after the `Project > Clean...` operation (which triggers a complete refresh and rebuild of the workspace) all classes should be processed and the *MapperImpl should be generated. In contrary they just get deleted as explained above.

Alltogether it seems like a bug in Eclipse or in the "annotation processor module" which isn't getting triggered during the build process (unless there have been changes in the relevant source files) - or let it be some feature (like some advanced indexing/ caching to only partially compile what's absolutely necessary).

I've checked the Eclipse error console and there is nothing noteworthy regarding MapStruct.

PS:

- On a colleagues machine it's working fine and the *MapperImpl classes are getting generated in IntelliJ - so the code itself should be fine.
- Also trying it with an older version of the MapStruct-Processor Jar (1.4.2.Final) didn't help
- MapStruct is the only annotation processor, we don't use lombok or so
- I also have installed the [m2e-apt plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) as a precaution like [mentioned here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_apache_maven), but also this didn't help (since as expected this probably only is needed when using it in combination with Maven/ Gradle)

Comment: Some idea's that might work:  
* use a new workspace, these are sometimes corrupted and can cause strange behaviour.  
* change the value of `Generated source directory` at the `Annotation Processing` inside the project properties. (No idea why, but just now when testing I didn't see it being generated for me until I changed this value.)

Comment: Hello Ben, thanks for your ideas! Before one observation from my side, which also is connected to what you mentioned. Because of some performance issues I disabled the option "Enable processing in editor". First of all it helped with the performance, second I was able to see the mapper classes being generated. Unfortunately I don't know if this was exactly the reason, since I was switching branches a lot and only was pointed to it because of an "Eclipse APT Annotation Processing error" saying "Classes already there". Now after switching branches again unfortunately they're gone again and

Comment: didn't come back yet. Why it's connected to your suggestions: Because a change in the settings might have triggered a refresh. BTW: It was also reported by a colleague, that Eclipse builds his classes only occasionally and he needs to trigger the generation with the manual file updates occasionally (but for him it's more like the exception and for me the rule - which makes it very interesting). Now regarding your suggestion: I tried to rename the folder in `Generated source directory` unfortunately it didn't help. Going to try with a new workspace now

Comment: Unfortunately also setting up a new workspace from scratch (by using the newer version of Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22.0) and Java 17 with Java 8 compatibility settings) didn't help - the `"generated"` folder still appears empty. Also changing the folder name in `Generated source directory` again didn't generate the classes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to make all the configurations, and then checking out the updated project into a new directory. I am wondering if some build cache is broken and Eclipse  uses some cached result, but doesn't recognize that the cached result is not using the annotation processor. Anyway, it is just a guess, I am not using Eclipse.

Comment: Hey there... I bumped into your question and happen to have the same problem with MapStruct. Then found this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52071186/460557 and configured mine for my purposes and it worked fine.